# Why @Value works differently in Spring Core & Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, spring-annotations

I have a simple `Spring Core` project where I am reading some values from `src/main/resources/application.properties` file.

Team.java

```java
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Test {
    @Value("${teamName}")
    private String teamName;
    @Value("${players}")
    private List<String> players;
}
```

App.java

```java
@ComponentScan
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(App.class);
        Team team = applicationContext.getBean(Team.class);
        System.out.println(team.getTeamName());
        System.out.println(team.getPlayers() + "   " + team.getPlayers().size());
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
teamName=Avengers
players=Iron Man,Captain America,Thor,Hulk
```

Output

```
Avengers
[Iron Man,Captain America,Thor,Hulk]   1
```

`teamName` is reading perfectly but when it comes to `players` it is reading all the players values as a single string. Ideally players size be should be `4` but got `1`. When I am changing `@Value("${players}")` to `@Value("#{'${players}'.split(',')}")` then it is working as expected. Means I am getting players size `4`.

Now the question is, with the same code in `Spring Boot` with `@Value("${players}")` give me players size as `4` but in the normal `Spring core` project gives me `1`. So what is the reason behind it and can you give me a solution which should work in the Spring core project? I mean what to do with `@Value("${players}")` so that I could get the players size as `4`?

Comment: Give this try: [Reading a List from properties file and load with spring annotation @Value](//stackoverflow.com/a/29970335)

Comment: Hi @Tom, I already read that doc then I posted this question. I have already mentioned in the question that when I am using `@Value("#{'${players}'.split(',')}")` then works as per the expectation which I took the help from this doc only. But when I am using `@Value("${players}")` then it does not work as per the expectation. But the same thing i.e. `@Value("${players}")` in `Spring Boot` gives me players size `4`. Why?

Comment: That answer I linked to doesn't use SpEL.

Answer (score 1):

*Spring Boot* and non-*Spring Boot* applications may behave differently if they are left off with **defaults** because *Spring Boot* uses a different set of configuration and bootstrapping tools, hence its need by the way.

One kind of this configuration difference is the injection of a basic `org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService` implementation `org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindConverter.TypeConverterConversionService` which allows property based conversion for simple types: primitives, arrays, collections...

To accommodate a non-*Spring Boot* application to behave the same, you need to inject a `org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService` implementation by yourself. If you are using a *Java*-based configuration, you can inject the `org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService` which is generally suitable for most cases:

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService;

@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ConversionService conversionService() {
        return new GenericConversionService();
    }

}
```